# "in as many weeks" and "as" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, as

I've seen a sentence like this:

> North Korea's internet appears to have been hit by a second wave of outages **in as many weeks**.

I wonder what does "in as many weeks" mean and specifically "as". Does sentence mean the same without "as"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been two 'waves of outages' in two weeks. That is, there were 'as many' (the same number of) weeks as there were 'waves'.